# Filter a nested serializer in Django REST Framework

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint that return a specific category with its all jobs and I want to apply some filters those jobs.

## Models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

```
class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    job_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=JOB_TYPE_CHOICES)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Egypt')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='jobs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

## Serializers

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = '__all__'

class CategoryJobsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    jobs = JobSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'jobs')
```

## Views

```
class ListCategoryJobs(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategoryJobsSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
```

I tried this but didn't work

```
class CategoryJobsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    jobs = JobSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'jobs')
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        # Filter the dishes to only include active dishes.
        instance.jobs = instance.jobs.filter(job_type="Full Time")

        # Return the filtered data.
        return super().to_representation(instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

### ----- Approach 1 ------

here **`source = "jobs"`** gives all jobs of its category

```
class CategoryJobsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    all_jobs = JobSerializer(source = "jobs", many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'all_jobs')
```

### ----- Approach 2 ------

You can get nested realation data using **`defth`** keyword like this

```
class CategoryJobsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        
        class Meta:
            model = Category
            fields = ('name', 'description', 'jobs')
            depth = 1  # Include one level of related objects (jobs)
```